# Used mirror modifier to create an object but don't want the texture to be mirrored

Tags: texturing, uv, mirror

So I want to texture clothing for example that I created using the mirror modifier. But I want the 2 sides of the clothing piece to have individual designs for instance but it is not possible since the original and the mirrored surfaces use the same UV-coordinates. How can I change that?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible without applying the mirror modifier, however I can look and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I guess applying it will work just fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here I have an image with a red squiggle on one side and blue on the other. I have a plane that is mirrored and I have enabled 'U' texture mirroring on the modifier to allow the other half of the texture to appear on the mirrored side.

[image]

Depending on your mirror axis you may want to enable 'V' mapping instead.

Comment: Beat me too it :D Nice feature! How new is it?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise It was present in 2.49 according to the wiki: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Mirror

Comment: How could one miss something so good o.O

Comment: Hehe, I missed it too :O.