# Mirror UVs: Keep Facial Seam on Middle Axis

Tags: texturing, uv

I have UVd a mesh with a Mirror Modifier on it. the mirroring itself works well, but I would like to keep some parts of the model together across the midline for easier texture painting changes down the pipeline.

So, **what I have** is this:

[image: What I got]

But **what I would like to get** is something more like this, where the face is still in one piece down the middle:

[image: What I need]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/full-uv-wrapping-on-a-mirrored-mesh and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27886/used-mirror-modifier-to-create-an-object-but-dont-want-the-texture-to-be-mirror. Note that mirroring drawing will happen around the image center so that's where you should put head unwrap (with its center seam to be on the center pixel of the image)

Comment: You mean I need to run a seam down the middle of the face and then manually move the middle-axis so it the UV-Island sits precisely on the middle axis of the UV-Map?

Comment: Yes, kind of like that. To easen the task select the middle seam and as it's going to be straight either way scale it to 0 by X axis, put 3D cursor to middle of the image (you can enter coordinates to cursor in UV editor window) and snap selection to Cursor. Pin those selected vertices and once you unwrap again island will move to the center itself. Downside is that if something is present on UV map you should redo it or pin as well

Comment: You can apply a second temporary mirror modifier, to force Blender to give you that straight middle seam: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKoaGfgPGpk) shows the workflow that I mean for non destructive UV mirroring.